# JAX: Passing a dictionary rather than arg nums to identify variables for autodifferentiation

Tags: python, gradient-descent, jax

I want to use JAX as a vehicle for gradient descent; however, I have a moderately large number of parameters and would prefer to pass them as a dictionary `f(func, dict)` rather than `f(func, x1, ...xn)`.

So instead of

```py
# https://www.kaggle.com/code/grez911/tutorial-efficient-gradient-descent-with-jax/notebook
def J(X, w, b, y):
    """Cost function for a linear regression. A forward pass of our model.

    Args:
        X: a features matrix.
        w: weights (a column vector).
        b: a bias.
        y: a target vector.

    Returns:
        scalar: a cost of this solution.    
    """
    y_hat = X.dot(w) + b # Predict values.
    return ((y_hat - y)**2).mean() # Return cost.

for i in range(100):
    w -= learning_rate * grad(J, argnums=1)(X, w, b, y)
    b -= learning_rate * grad(J, argnums=2)(X, w, b, y)
```

Something more like

```py
for i in range(100):
    w -= learning_rate * grad(J, arg_key='w')(arg_dict)
    b -= learning_rate * grad(J, arg_key='b')(arg_dict)
```

Is this possible?

**EDIT**:

This is my current work around solution:

```py
# A features matrix.
X = np.array([
                 [4., 7.],
                 [1., 8.],
                 [-5., -6.],
                 [3., -1.],
                 [0., 9.]
             ])

# A target column vector.
y = np.array([
                 [37.],
                 [24.],
                 [-34.], 
                 [16.],
                 [21.]
             ])

learning_rate = 0.01

w = np.zeros((2, 1))
b = 0.

import jax.numpy as np
from jax import grad

def J(X, w, b, y):
    """Cost function for a linear regression. A forward pass of our model.

    Args:
        X: a features matrix.
        w: weights (a column vector).
        b: a bias.
        y: a target vector.

    Returns:
        scalar: a cost of this solution.    
    """
    y_hat = X.dot(w) + b # Predict values.
    return ((y_hat - y)**2).mean() # Return cost.

# Define your function arguments as a dictionary
arg_dict = {
    'X': X,
    'w': w,
    'b': b,
    'y': y
}
idx_dict = {idx:name for idx,name in enumerate(arg_dict.keys())}
arg_arr = [arg_dict[idx_dict[idx]] for idx in range(len(arg_dict))]

for i in range(100):
  for idx, name in idx_dict.items():
    var = arg_dict[idx_dict[idx]]
    var -= learning_rate * grad(J, argnums=idx) (*arg_arr)
```

The gist is that now I don't need to write grad(...) for every single variable that needs autodifferentiation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specifying autodiff argnums by name is not currently supported in JAX, although the idea is under discussion in this issue: https://github.com/google/jax/issues/10614

Until that is implemented, there are ways you can convert argnames to argnums automatically using `inspect.signature` for your function (some examples are in the linked issue), but overall it's probably simpler to do that mapping manually for your specific function.